# how do you use Axios to create a preview of a page in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, axios, fetch

I have never used Axios before and i am new to the fetch Api, could I have some advice on how to display a URL preview within a website?

The best I have as an example of the code I would like is below:

In the not working code, I used the fetch API to try and change the state of coverImageURL to the image of the link that will be clicked (boards). Though it does not work.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        setDigit({ id:mapper.length +1,
            text:JSON.stringify(myRef.current.innerHTML)
            });        

            fetch("/boards")
  //                         vvvv
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(images => {
      setCoverImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(images));
      console.log(coverImageUrl)
  })

 },[bool])
```

Comment: What is at `/boards`? An image or a webpage?

Comment: a page of the current website.

so localStorage/boards

the aim is to it as one of the boards in boards/:id as an image next to the link tot he page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a screenshot of a webpage.

`response.blob()` will not give you that. It is simply a Blob representation of whatever comes over the wire. In the case of HTML, converting HTML text to a Blob does not create an image of any kind. Not only that, but most webpages have additional content that a browser will request to properly render the page (css/images/APIs). A single fetch to the page URL will get you none of that content, unless it is all inlined. The fetch API couldn't assemble anything resembling your webpage even if it did make all those requests.

There are link previewer libraries out there (search google/github/npm or check out this [link](https://winhtaikaung.github.io/react-tiny-link/)) but those just give some metadata and an image taken *from* the page. I am sure you have run into these link previews in the wild.

If you must show a screenshot of a webpage, you can try something like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) but you will need a backend server for that and it will be nothing close to resembling a realtime user experience in terms of latency...

Edit: if the content is static for the most part (changes infrequently), and you only need previews of local links, you can have your build server generate these images using something like puppeteer and save them as assets. Depending on your needs, that may be an option....

Comment: shame there is no front end only option.